# Online database Engine for SQL Server 2008?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, windows-server-2008

I already have a student version of SQL Server 2008. I used to have a student account which allows me to connect through the university server but since I've graduated I haven't had a chance to create my own databases. I can log on using my LocalHost. But I need to access my database online via php from my website. Could anyone tell me if there are any websites that can give me the opportunity to create online tables and use them via PHP? I have been searching for 2 days straight. I don't know what to search for anymore.

Comment: It's a long shot, but you could try using https://appharbor.com. They'll host a mysql/sqlserver instance for you for free, i believe, up to 20mgs  in size. You could hit it with your PHP code from an arbitrary location.

Comment: *I have been searching for 2 days straight* Can't tell if trolling... http://bit.ly/HlwOwC @SergeyAkopov has the right idea though, start with AppHarbor.

Comment: Was the SQL server software licensed to you or did you just have access to it?